# How do I grep a date pattern from a list of csv files in powershell?

Tags: powershell, grep

I have a list of files in a directory with different dates as such:

```
1. test_2017-01-01.csv
2. test_2017-02-01.csv
3. test_2017-03-01.csv
4. test_2017-04-01.csv
```

Let's say I want to pull all the files into a new list labeled `$files` that holds only files between the dates of 2017-01-01 and 2017-03-01. How would I go about this? I Can pull from the directory at the moment as such:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "my_directory" | Sort-Object
```

Comment: `$files = GCI 'my_directory' | ?{[datetime]'1/1/2017' -le $_.basename.split('_')[-1] -and [datetime]'3/1/2017' -ge $_.basename.split('_')[-1]}`

Comment: I am getting an error with this solution: Could not compare "01/01/2017 00:00:00" to "". Error: "Cannot convert value "" to type "System.DateTime". Error:
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.""

Comment: If that doesn't work then your file names likely aren't formatted as you suggested. Perhaps replace `$_.basename.split('_')[-1]` with `($_.basename -replace '.*(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d).*', '$1')` instead to strip the date string out of your file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure this can be easily transformed to date format query. Do you think regex would work for you in this case?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "^test_2017-0[123]{1}-01.csv$"}
```

There is quite some long one-liner, but it does what you are after - converts the numeric string in the name of file (has to have format of yyyy-MM-dd) to date and then evaluates whether it's in range specified.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {($_.Name -match "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}") -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}").Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}").Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))}
```

Comment: this works to pull a file for that one date, how might I build a range for this?

Comment: Try to look for Regular Expressions. You can pretty nicely (not saying the easiest way) specify what you are after.

Comment: Also extended my answer with quite hard to read one-liner. Hope it helps