# Issue escaping characters running powershell in R

Tags: r, powershell

Trying to run a powershell command in R specifically to filter a directory for dates, this is based of a question I asked previously:

[How do I grep a date pattern from a list of csv files in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580501/how-do-i-grep-a-date-pattern-from-a-list-of-csv-files-in-powershell/57580612?noredirect=1#comment101621788_57580612)

The issue is when implementing this within R's system command:

```
files = system('powershell -command "Get-ChildItem \'D:/my_directory\' | Where-Object {($_.Name -match \'[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\') -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\').Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\').Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))})"', intern = T)
```

original:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:/shl" | Where-Object {($_.Name -match "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}") -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}").Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, "[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}").Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))}
```

seems I am not escaping properly?

```
Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'powershell -command "Get-ChildItem \'D:/my_directory\' | Where-Object {($_.Name -match \'[\d"
```

Attempted the solution proposed:

```
system('powershell -command "Get-ChildItem \'my_directory\' | Where-Object {($_.Name -match \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\') -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))})"', intern = T)
```

Got the following warning:

```
[1] "At line:1 char:283"                                                                   
[2] "+ ... _.Name, '[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}').Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))})"       
[3] "+                                                                         ~"          
[4] "Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement."                                     
[5] "    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException"
[6] "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken"                                        
[7] " "                                                                                    
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
```

UPDATE:

fixed:

```
system('powershell -command "Get-ChildItem \'D:/my_directory\' | Where-Object {($_.Name -match \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\') -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))}"')
```

Comment: I'd recommend building the vector of arguments and use `shQuote`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `\` is being used as the escape character in `'...'` string literals in R.

Therefore, in order to pass a *literal* `\` char. through, you'll have to `\`-escape it, i.e, *double* it; in your case, that means representing `\d` instances to be passed through to the regex engine as `\\d`:

```
files = system('powershell -command "Get-ChildItem \'D:/my_directory\' | Where-Object {($_.Name -match \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\') -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -ge (Get-Date 2017/01/01)) -and ([datetime][regex]::Match($_.Name, \'[\\d]{4}-[\\d]{2}-[\\d]{2}\').Value -le (Get-Date 2017/03/01))})"')
```

What the error message is telling you is that *R* (rather than PowerShell) is trying to interpret escape sequence `\d`, which happens not to be a supported one.